# Related Implement Custom images and select all images from textview and paste

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I am working on an **Emoji** type application in which I used my custom images that images show on `UITextView`, now I want to select all images and copy those images. After copying those images I want to paste those images in a message text box but i don't know how to implement this functionality. Is it possible or not ? It only copies the text but cannot not copy images, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html).
Put all the images in an array and then add the array to UIPasteboard.

You can use method:

```
- (void)addItems:(NSArray *)items
```

Hope this helps.